# Share code with composition Api in Vue (defineProps, defineEmits and defineExpose)

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, code-reuse

I'm migrating a midlevel app from Vue 2 to Vue 3.

For this task, I'm rewrittig all code to make use of Composition Api. I like Composition Api, however, I don't see a good advantage when simplifying code. With Composition Api, somethings looks more complex or verbose than before. I hope be wrong.

This becomes specially noticiable when refactoring mixings. When using mixins, you just have to use them and that's enought to get all desired functionality, while when using composables, you have to be aware of what is inside the composable to extract/use specific functionality from composable...

My main problem arises when I want to reuse `defineProps()`, `defineEmits()` and `defineExpose()`.

In some parte of my app, I got all posible inputs defined in different components, for example:

- InputText: Just text
- InputNumber: Reusing InputText, limiting to only numbers
- InputMoney: Reusing InputNumber, adding some money formatting
- InputNumberRange: Reusing two InputNumbers
- etc

As you can imagine, all that inputs are almost the same. The needed code for those components are very small, just a InputMixin and a couple of overwrites if needed.

However, when using Composition Api, I don't know how to get it so simple because I don't know how to 'share' the code between these components. **How could I reuse `defineProps()`, `defineEmits()` and `defineExpose()` between them?**

Is it possible to use some kind of inheritance? (like `extends: MyComponent`)

Comment: What do you mean by `reuse defineProps(), defineEmits() and defineExpose()`. BTW. I've found composition api far easier than options api.

Comment: I want a **single `defineEmits()`** for my three components instead of place three `defineEmits()` inside each one. I dont know if that is possible.

Comment: Yes. If course it is. Have you read the docs?

Comment: Hmm but I cant figure out how to do that. When reading [docs](https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#defineprops-defineemits), it says that `defineProps()` and `defineEmits()` are compiler macros, only usable inside `<script setup>`. So, the way I have seen for reusability are **composables**, however, if I create a composable with `defineProps()` it throws an error, because defineProps() does not exists outside `<script setup>`. I would love to have a single place where I can write a single `defineProps()` that I can reuse in multiple `<script setup>`